# multicore parallelism with stack runghc

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, haskell-stack

I had been working on a [script](https://haskell-lang.org/tutorial/stack-script) in which I hoped to take advantage of multiple processors in my machine by swapping out `mapM` with [`Async.mapConcurrently`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.1.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:mapConcurrently).

Observing no speed increase in that instance, I wanted to verify that `runghc` can indeed utilize multiple cores.

Given a file `Foo.hs`:

```
import Control.Concurrent

main = print =<< Control.Concurrent.getNumCapabilities
```

If I compile the file as follows:

```
stack ghc -- -threaded Foo.hs
```

and then run it as follows:

```
./Foo
```

it returns the result `1`.  This is expected, as no RTS options have been supplied.  Running it instead as follows:

```
./Foo +RTS -N
```

returns the number `6`, as there are 6 processors in my machine (agreeing with `nproc`).

However, when I run the script in "interpreted mode" like so:

```
GHCRTS="-N" stack runghc Foo.hs
```

It yields the following error text:

```
Running /home/kostmo/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-nopie-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db list --global exited with ExitFailure 1

ghc-pkg: the flag -N requires the program to be built with -threaded
```

Is it possible to utilize multiple cores with stack "scripts"?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for asking this question, I think stack should handle the GHCRTS environment variable specially, and opened this issue https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3444 and made this change https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/pull/3445

Unfortunately, it does not solve this case, because `runghc` itself (ghc) will process `GHCRTS`, and it is not built with the threaded runtime.  So the environment variable solution cannot be used.

I think it should be possible to provide `-with-rtsopts -N` flag to `stack script --compile`, but that doesn't seem to be working, needs further investigation.   This doesn't work with `runghc`, because it uses the interpreter.