# Why does this TCP server immediately exit?

Tags: haskell, tcp, conduit, stm

This is an extraction I did from a larger project, which didn't seem to have the issue of the server immediately returning (I'll admit the reason I did the extraction in the first place was in the hope of asking a different question regarding failure of `accept`, so there may be other issues with the code).

I wouldn't think running with fewer threads (well, one thread) would be an issue, but [TCP.serve](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-simple-0.4.5/docs/Network-Simple-TCP.html#v:serve) seems to silently return:

```
starting tcp server
exgetting protobuf port
iting serveTBQ
tcp server exited
```

The expected behavior is that this would continue running, listening on the specified port (`getPort`).

Here is the self-contained example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack script --nix --resolver lts-14.27
  --nix-packages zlib
  --no-nix-pure
  --package bytestring
  --package classy-prelude
  --package conduit
  --package exceptions
  --package mtl
  --package network
  --package network-simple
  --package stm
  --package stm-conduit
  --package text
  --package unliftio
  --ghc-options -Wall
-}

-- Use --verbose above for better error messages for library build failures
--  --package refined
--   --extra-dep unexceptionalio-0.5.1

{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes                  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables         #-}

module Main where

import           ClassyPrelude                    hiding (hClose)
import           Conduit
import           Control.Concurrent.STM.TBQueue   (TBQueue, writeTBQueue)
import           Control.Monad.Catch              (MonadMask)
import           Control.Monad.Writer
import           Data.Bits                        (shiftR, (.&.))
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8            as B
import           Data.Conduit.Async               (gatherFrom)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List                as CL
import           Data.Function                    ((&))
import qualified Data.Text                        as T
import           GHC.IO.Handle                    (Handle, hClose)
import qualified Network.Simple.TCP               as TCP
import qualified Network.Socket                   as NS
import           UnliftIO.Concurrent              (ThreadId, forkIO, threadDelay)

type Error = [String]
type Result r = Writer Error r

runResult :: Result r -> (r, Error)
runResult = runWriter

getPort :: NS.ServiceName
getPort = "29876"

-- | This signature is meant to simulate the same function from the proto-lens library,
-- | but without dealing with protobus for binary data.
decodeMessageDelimitedH :: Handle -> IO (Either String String)
decodeMessageDelimitedH h = do
    sOut <- B.hGetLine h
    pure $ Right $ B.unpack sOut

protoServe :: forall m. (MonadMask m, MonadResource m, MonadUnliftIO m) =>
     (String -> Result [String])
  -> ConduitT () [String] m ()
protoServe fromProto = start .| mapMC logFilterRead
  .| CL.catMaybes .| mapMC msgToRecs
  where
    port = trace "getting protobuf port" getPort
    start = do
      let enQserver = serveTBQ (TCP.HostIPv4) port (decodeProto . fst)
      gatherFrom 10000 enQserver
    decodeProto :: NS.Socket -> m (Either String String)
    decodeProto sock = bracket
      connHandleIO
      (liftIO . hClose)
      (liftIO . decodeMessageDelimitedH)
      where
        connHandleIO :: m Handle
        connHandleIO = liftIO $ sockToHandle sock
    logFilterRead :: Either String String -> m (Maybe String)
    logFilterRead pEi = case pEi of
      Right p -> pure $ Just p
      Left err -> trace err $ pure Nothing
    msgToRecs :: String -> m [String]
    msgToRecs p = case runResult $ fromProto p of
      (rs, rErr) -> do
        when (not $ null rErr) $ pure $ trace (intercalate "\n" rErr) ()
        pure $ trace "completed msgToRecs" rs

-- | The handle only needs a read-view of the socket.  Note that a TBQeueue is
-- | mutable but has STM's runtime safety checks in place.
sockToHandle :: NS.Socket -> IO Handle
sockToHandle sock = NS.socketToHandle sock ReadMode

-- | Based on serve and listen from Network.Simple.TCP
-- | Unlike `serve`, which never returns, `serveTBQ` immediately returns
-- | a `TBQueue` of results.
serveTBQ :: forall a m. (MonadMask m, MonadUnliftIO m)
  => TCP.HostPreference -- ^ Host to bind.
  -> NS.ServiceName -- ^ Server service port name or number to bind.
  -> ((NS.Socket, NS.SockAddr) -> m a)
  -- ^ Computation to run in a different thread once an incoming connection is
  -- accepted. Takes the connection socket and remote end address.
  -> TBQueue a -- ^ enqueue computation results to this queue
  -> m ()
  -- ^ Returns a FIFO (queue) of results from concurrent requests
serveTBQ hp port rFun tbq = do
    _ <- async $ withRunInIO $ \run -> TCP.serve hp port $ \(lsock, _) -> do
      run $ void $ acceptTBQ lsock rFun tbq
    putStrLn $ T.pack "exiting serveTBQ"

-- | Based on acceptFork from Network.Simple.TCP.
acceptTBQ :: forall a m.
  MonadUnliftIO m
  => NS.Socket -- ^ Listening and bound socket.
  -> ((NS.Socket, NS.SockAddr) -> m a)
  -- ^ Computation to run in a different thread once an incoming connection is
  -- accepted. Takes the connection socket and remote end address.
  -> TBQueue a
  -> m ThreadId
acceptTBQ lsock rFun tbq = mask $ \restore -> do
  (csock, addr) <- trace ("running restore-accept on lsock: " <> (show lsock)) $ restore (liftIO $ NS.accept lsock)
  onException (forkIO $ finally
    (restore $ do
      rVal <- trace "retrieved rVal in finally-restore" rFun (csock, addr)
      atomically $ writeTBQueue tbq rVal)
    (TCP.closeSock csock))
    (TCP.closeSock csock)

retryForever :: forall m a. MonadUnliftIO m => m a -> m a
retryForever prog = catchAny prog progRetry
  where
    progRetry :: SomeException -> m a
    progRetry ex = do
      putStrLn $ pack $ show ex
      threadDelay 4000000
      retryForever prog

-- | Safer interface to sinkNull
sinkUnits :: MonadResource m => ConduitT () Void m ()
sinkUnits = sinkNull

main :: IO ()
main = retryForever $ do
  putStrLn $ T.pack "starting tcp server"
  let myProtoServe = protoServe (pure . words)
  myProtoServe .| mapMC (putStrLn . T.pack . intercalate "_") .| sinkUnits & runConduitRes
  putStrLn $ T.pack "tcp server exited"
```

Maybe there is a way to get this working with multiple threads while still remaining a stack script? see [multicore parallelism with stack runghc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311648/multicore-parallelism-with-stack-runghc)

Comment: I added a project that demonstrates the issue persists when built with `-threaded` and run as an executable: https://github.com/bbarker/tcpConduitServer

Comment: I pushed a commit to the example rep above, where I seem to have narrowed it down to `bindSock` not succeeding

Comment: The plot thickens ... I realized after importing `bindSock` to my own app that the performance must have changed in a subtle way, such that different print calls were being emitted. i then played a `threadDelay` right before `serveTBQ` exits, which allowed `bindSock` and `serve` to execute. This makes me wonder if `gatherFrom` is somehow terminating prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the reason the extracted server example terminates is because the program itself eventually exits, which terminates all other threads (including the one the server is running in), whereas in my actual application, the main thread already had loops in place to prevent this.

So just adding something like this to the end of the main IO action worked:

```
waitForever :: IO ()
waitForever = do
  threadDelay 10000
  waitForever
```

Thanks to @ProofOfKeags on slack for the hint.